# How can this data be joined?

Tags: mysql, query, join

Definition:

```
table_A                table_B
id,description         id,description,id_table_A
```

Column `id_table_A` is a foreign key to the primary key of `table_A` and is not mandatory.

Sample data:

```
table_A                 
1,some_desc_1        
2,some_desc_2

table_B
1,some_desc_1,1        
2,some_desc_2,2
3,some_desc_aaa,null
4,some_desc_bbb,null
```

I need to write a query that shows me all the records, including the records with the foreign key set to null.  What type of join is this?  I'm not able to show the records with null foreign key using an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Outer joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_join#Outer_joins)...

```
SELECT *
FROM
    table_B B
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    table_A A ON B.id_table_A = A.id
;
```